# How to Hide iOS 14 Widget Content when iPhone is locked?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I have a widget that displays some sensitive data. We know that the iOS widgets can be placed both on the home screen and the Today widget page.

`Today widget page` page can be visible even from the locked state! Here is the problem that arises, I want to hide the content if the user locked their mobile.

I can see this behavior has done in the iOS `Screen Time` widget. If we locked the mobile no data is exposed. Once if I unlock (AKA activate the Face ID), All the data is visible.

## Locked State

[image: Locked State]

## Unlocked State

[image: Unlocked State]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it by enabling Data Protection Capability

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension

You need to set the Data Protection Entitlement

> NSFileProtectionComplete or NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen, and the device is locked.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_default-data-protection

In Swift 5.5 iOS 15+ there is a new `ViewModifier`

```
.privacySensitive(true)
```

Just add it to the `View` that has the sensitive content

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10018/

Comment: It may take sometime for the widget to update with the system to have this feature.

Comment: For iOS 15 apple has added a new view modifier